# Django Search error: Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: python, django, search, csrf

iam trying to develop search function to my system.
From Firefox inspect network - preview - iam getting:

```
Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Help

Reason given for failure:

CSRF token missing or incorrect.


In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django's CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:

Your browser is accepting cookies.
The view function uses RequestContext for the template, instead of Context.
In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.

You're seeing the help section of this page because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and only the initial error message will be displayed.

You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.
```

And it is very strange because i have included the tag.

Bellow i am providing the code that might be necessary to detect what is wrong.

reviewallcases2.html:

```
...
<section>

<h3>Search by patient id</h3>
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" id="search" name="search"/>

<ul id="search-results">

</ul>

</section>

...
```

views.py:

```
...
def search_id(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        search_text = request.POST['search_text']
    else:
        search_text = ''

patients = Patient.objects.filter(patient_id__contains=search_text)

return render_to_response('ajax_search.html', {'patients' : patients})
```

Comment: The second item in the list of possible causes is the one relevant to you. Use the `render` shortcut, not `render_to_response`, as it uses a RequestContext.

Comment: Django has some docs on how to properly send ajax requests. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax - try to include the @ensure_csrf_token to your ajax view as well.

Comment: @DanielRoseman if i change views.py last line to :
`return render(request, 'ajax_search.html', {'patients' : patients}, content_type="application/xhtml+xml"))`

i get this error:

`Exception Type: SyntaxError at /accounts/loggedin/reviewallcases/search/
Exception Value: invalid syntax (views.py, line 98)
Request information:
GET: No GET data`

Comment: @Martol1ni thanks for the suggestion too. `@csrf_exempt` in the views.py did the job done. By the way, what is that `@ensure_csrf_token` ?